# Limpiar modal, al dar cancelar

Tags: javascript, html

Como podría hacerle para que al momento de dar cancelar en el modal, el tag de la imagen quede en limpio de nuevo ya que se queda con la opción elegida anteriormente.

Este es el html:

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-lg-3">
   <p id="previewEditar"><img src="http://localhost/WareHouse/assets/img/no-image.jpg" id="imagenEditar" class="animated fadeInDown img-rounded" width="200px">
   </p>
</div>
```

Tengo esta function en el boton de cancel:

```
function clearModal()   // document.getElementById('imageName').value="";dal()
{
    $('#myModal').modal('hide');        
    $('.has-error').removeClass("has-error");
    document.getElementById("errorMessageOutputEdit").style.display = "none";
    $("#botonSubir").val('');

   // line para dejar en blanco, donde se muestra la imagen.
   document.getElementById('imagenEditar').value="";    
}
```

Hice esa linea de código pero no funciona sigue con la imagen de la opcin elegida, no sale en limpio.

Comment: prueba vaciando el src en lugar del value

Comment: Quieres limpiar el tag `div` o el tag `img` ?

Comment: seria el tag, cuando preciono un boton x, me muestra su imagen, cuando le doy cancelar necesito que la proxima vez que abra el modal este en blanco, no con la imagen anterior.

Comment: y ya intentaste con `$('#imagenEditar').attr('src', '');`

Comment: o con `$('#imagenEditar').removeAttr('src');`

Answer (score 0):

Agrégale un ID a tu formulario y posteriormente puedes hacerlo con JQUERY, te dejo 2 opciones:

Primera Opción

$('#miFormulario')[0].reset();

Segunda Opción

$('#miFormulario').trigger("reset");